# Django Crispy forms hide fields conditional on other field value

Tags: javascript, django, show-hide, django-crispy-forms

How can I hide/show a form field in Django crispy forms based on the value of another field in the form.

E.g. 
Field A has a dropdown with choices '1' and '2'
Field B is show when Field A = '1'
Field C is shown when Field A = '2'
All other fields are shown in regular ways

I've tried multiple query/javascript solutions from the forums, but they don't seem to work on crispy forms.

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568290/jquery-javascript-method-to-show-hide-multiple-fields-upon-selection-with-common) , [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136657/show-and-hide-dynamically-fields-in-django-form) , [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190345/django-crispy-form-use-radio-button-to-hide-show-other-fields)

Maybe I'm misunderstanding these solutions or they just won't work on Crispy forms.

Models.py

```
class TestCondition(models.Model):
    some_name = models.ForeignKey(key_name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    A_type_choices = (
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
    )
    Field_A = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= A_type_choices,default='1')
    B_field_choices = (
        ('abc','ABC'),
        ('cba','CBA'),
    )
    Field_B = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices= B_field_choices,default='abc',blank=True,)
    Field_C = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, default='')
```

views.py

```
class ViewUpdateTestCondition(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    model = TestCondition
    template_name = 'update.html'
    form_class = TestConditionForm

class TestConditionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCondition
        fields = ('some_name','Field_A','Field_B','Field_C')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelconfigForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post' # this line sets your form's method to post

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                'Test Condition',
                Field('some_name', type='hidden'),
                ('Field_A','Field_B','Field_C')),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', "Save changes")
            )   
        )
```

Update.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block content %}
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="{% static 'formset/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
        <script>
    function Hide() {
        if(document.getElementById('id_Field_A').options[document.getElementById('Field_A').selectedIndex].value == "1") {
             document.getElementById('id_Field_B').style.display = 'none';
             document.getElementById('id_Field_C').style.display = '';
        } else {
             document.getElementById('id_Field_B').style.display = '';
             document.getElementById('id_Field_C').style.display = 'none';
        }
    };  </script>
         {% load crispy_forms_tags %} 
         {% crispy form form.helper%}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where's the code to trigger that function `Hide()` ?

Comment: Ah true good point. I was using the example from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136657/show-and-hide-dynamically-fields-in-django-form
But there it has an onchange="Hide()" trigger. How would I implement such a trigger in crispy forms?

Comment: You may add an [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) at the bottom of your template to target the dropdown, for the `change` event

Comment: Thanks art06!
I have added the following and works like a charm.
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.addEventListener("load", Hide);</script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     var el = document.getElementById("div_id_Field_A");
     el.addEventListener("click", Hide);</script>

Comment: Cool! Didn't know the django form field names got passed as "id_<field name>" to the template by default... Is this overridable?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks art06! I have added the following and works like a charm.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.addEventListener("load", Hide);</script> <script type="text/javascript"> var el = document.getElementById("div_id_Field_A"); el.addEventListener("click", Hide);</script>
```